# SQL Server copy tables only if changed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on a project. I have two databases with identical tables that are on different servers but on the same network. I want to only copy tables that are different. So `DB_A` has `table_1` and `table_2` and so does `DB_B`. During the day `DB_A.table_1` had some modified rows and rows added. I want SQL Server to be able to update the rows that have been modified and added in `DB_A.table_1` to `DB_B.table_1`. My first thought is to write a script that deletes the row in `DB_B.table_1` and do an INSERT INTO statement from `DB_A.table_1` and schedule it as a job to run at night. This can take a long time because `DB_A.table_1` might have 10000 Rows. The example I just gave is a really simple one. In reality, I could be updating 100+ tables. Is there a function within SQL SERVER 2008 r2 to do this easily? Maybe with SSIS?

Comment: If you want to only copy data that has changed in a table include a lastupdatedate column in the table and then only query the data that was updated since the last time you moved data from one server to another.  Also this is something SSIS is great for.

Comment: How about Transaction replication 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Have you thought about just replacing database B with a backup of database A? My experience with SQL Server is that this is a fairly quick operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Change Tracking` for this. Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Enable Change Tracking in the Database level as well as in the Table level. Create a job and schedule it in a minimum interval to push the data from the database to another.

Or use `UPDATE / INSERT Trigger` to copy the changed data directly from one server to another.

I prefer `Change Tracking` as its easy to implement.

Hope this will help.